# Updating mysql tables based on a join

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT `pro`.`St`, `sho`.`Q`
FROM `sho`
 LEFT JOIN `web`.`pro` ON `sho`.`Pro_id` = `pro`.`ProdID`
```

the above MySQL code produces a table like

```
st q
1  23
4  24
```

st is from one table and q is from another
how would i use this query to update the st row from the first table by adding q to it from the second?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: if updated, `st` with value of `1` will become `23` or `24` (1 + 23)?

Comment: Becaus  1 can be 2,3,4... and 24 could be 49 ect it needs to be taken from that colum from the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
UPDATE  pro a
        INNER JOIN sho b ON b.Pro_id = a.Proid
SET     a.st = b.q
```

*please do have a backup on your table before executing this*

Comment: i didn't understand what you say, can you explain a little bit?

Comment: basically what im trying to do is add a row from a join to the column of another table together